# Regex matching groups

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an issue with replaceAll function of Java string

```
replaceAll("regex", "replacement");
```

works fine but whenever my "replacement" string contains the substring like "$0", "$1" .e.t.c, it will create problem by substituting these $x's with corresponding matching group.

For instance

```
input ="NAME";
input.replaceAll("NAME", "HAR$0I");
```

will result in a string "HARNAMEI" as the replacement string contains "$0" which will be substituted by matching group "NAME". How can I override that nature. I need to get the result string as "HAR$0I" only.

I escaped the $ .i.e I converted the replacement string to "HAR\\$0I" which worked fine. But I am looking for any method in java that will do this for me for all such characters which has special meaning in regex world.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't actually be using regex / `replaceAll()`.

Comment: replaceAll assumes the first parameter as regex and that is the reason the matching group "$0" contains the first parameter for back reference purpose in this case "NAME"

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [java.lang.String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   [Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

The documentation of [String quoteReplacement(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Returns a literal replacement String for the specified String. This
>   method produces a String that will work as a literal replacement s in
>   the appendReplacement method of the Matcher class. The String produced
>   will match the sequence of characters in s treated as a literal
>   sequence. Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no
>   special meaning.

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to approve this answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`$` in `replacement` is special character allowing you to use groups. To make it literal you will need to escape it with `\$` which needs to be written as `"\\$"`. Same rule apply for `\`, since it is special character used to escape `$`. If you would like to use `\` literal in replacement you would also need to escape it with another `\`, so you would need to write it as `\\\\`.

To simplify this process you can just use `Matcher.quoteReplacement("yourReplacement"))`.

---

In case where you don't need to use regular expression you can simplify it even more and use

```
replace("NAME", "HAR$0I")
```

instead of

```
replaceAll("NAME", Matcher.quoteReplacement("HAR$0I"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're actually trying to replace raw strings, without using regexes at all.

You should simply call [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2C%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which does literal replacements without using regexes.